# Adding info icons after InputText or InputRadioGroup in Blazor app editform

Tags: html, css, blazor, font-awesome, blazor-webassembly

I just want to add info icon "i" after InputRadioGroup of my Razor page. I tried out something but it's not working. Any suggestions here?

added link in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

added `<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>` in editform.
Something like below:

```
                 <div class="form-group col">
                   <label>My Role in this trade</label><br />
                    <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="model.Role" class="form-control">
                        @foreach (var option in rdOptions)
                        {
                            <InputRadio Value="option" /> @option
                            <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
                        }
                    </InputRadioGroup> <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.Role)" />
                </div>
```

No error. But no info icon either.

Comment: Can you get any other fa fonts to work?

Comment: Fa fonts are not working for me at all. I tried adding trash icon in one of the html tables but its just showing a compressed rectangle kind.

Comment: Hey Henk, it worked. Please check my posted answer. Unexpected but true :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched more into this. I was just wondering, even though all the links are correct why fonts are not working for me . I tried below solution which i found in other stackoverflow questions. Worked like a charm. I used chrome option. Hope this helps someone in future.

Sometimes forced reload fixes the problem. You need to reload the browser's caché memory.

```
Firefox: ctrl + shift + R
Chrome: ctrl + right click on Chrome's reload button
Edge: Same as Chrome, or ctrl + F5
Other combinations can be found in the above provided link.
```